# Latest bootstrap doesn't react properly on navbar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I have installed `Bootstrap` v.:

```
 "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta"
```

And I wannted to implemented `nav bar` so I creted:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded" *ngIf="!isLogged">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active" routerLinkActive="active current">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/sign-up"><span class="sr-only">Sign Up</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active" routerLinkActive="active current">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login"><span class="sr-only">Login</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Whereas it displays me `nav` but what I see is:

[image]

And what is more this button which should doesn't toggle. What is more this look should be when browser is in mobile mode, but in above example isn't.

And the result which I would like to achieve should be the first example from:
[example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the latest Bootstrap v4 Beta, you need to change `navbar-toggleable-md` to `navbar-expand-md`

Example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-faded" *ngIf="!isLogged">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active" routerLinkActive="active current">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/sign-up"><span class="sr-only">Sign Up</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active" routerLinkActive="active current">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login"><span class="sr-only">Login</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

The reason for this is because the syntax changed between the alpha and beta versions of Bootstrap v4.

And here is the latest documentation showing `navbar-expand-**` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

EDIT: Based on your other issues in the comments.
You won't see the sign up and login text on any screen because you've assigned them the class `sr-only` which makes them viewable on screen readers only. Remove the `sr-only` classes to view the text.

You also need to change `bg-faded` to `bg-light`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light" *ngIf="!isLogged">
  <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active" routerLinkActive="active current">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/sign-up"><span class="">Sign Up</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item active" routerLinkActive="active current">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login"><span class="">Login</span></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Your question is about getting the toggler working. This question allows the toggler to function on screens smaller than 767px which is the medium size cutoff. You won't see the sign up and login text on any screen because you've assigned them the class sr-only which makes them viewable on screen readers only. Remove the sr-only classes to view the text.

Comment: one more question - how to make a button clickable when browser get mobile size? When I do it, I can't expand that button?

Comment: Make sure you're using jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js, popper.min.js and bootstrap.min.js. See here for details https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: `"styles": [
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.slim.min.js",
        "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.min.js",
        "styles.css"
      ],` doesn't work

Comment: Are there any error's in your browsers debug console?

Comment: I recommend opening a new question since it's outside the remit of this current question.